# Leaflet - GeoJSON file can't be loaded on the map

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson

I don't know where I make mistake.

It's probably silly mistake, but I cannot load my geojson on the map.

I tried the Leaflet "getting started" standalone example and it worked. Unfortunately my example doesn't at all.

The link to GeoJSON file (described as `var =`  and turned into JavaScript is in the link below).

https://jsfiddle.net/5jpwh1md/

and the full code below:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([39.74739, -105], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    id: 'mapbox/light-v9',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1
}).addTo(map);

 var path = L.geoJSON(ecl, {
   style: function (feature) {
      return {color: feature.properties.color};
     }
   }).bindPopup(function (layer) {
   return layer.feature.properties.description;
   }).addTo(map);
```

Can anyone advise, where this silly mistake might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your GeoJSON won't show is that it's coordinates are in projected `EPSG:3857` CRS. Standard for GeoJSON coordinates is unprojected `[lon, lat]`.

Solution for this is to use `coordsToLatLng` method when creating GeoJSON layer, to convert projected to unprojected coordinates with the `L.CRS.EPSG3857.unproject` method.

Code could then look something like this (by the way, name of the property for popup in your GeoJSON is `descriptio`, not `description` - probably typo):

```
var path = L.geoJSON(ecl, {
  style: function (feature) {
    return {color: feature.properties.color};
  },
  coordsToLatLng: function (coords) {
    var latLng = L.CRS.EPSG3857.unproject(L.point(coords)); 
    return latLng;
  }
}).bindPopup(function (layer) {
  return layer.feature.properties.descriptio;
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: OK I see nnow. Thanks A LOT. So it means, that in my QGIS should I save the geojson file not projected right?

Comment: Yes, it you want to avoid unprojecting.